# elif in list comprehension using python conditionals

Tags: list-comprehension, python-3.7

for example

```py
for p in list(extracted_data):
  if (p >= 80):
     print ('orange')
  elif(80 > p >= 60):
     print ('red')
  else:
     print('yellow')
```

Is there any list comprehension for the same.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

`x = [ 'orange' if p>=80 else 'red' if 80>p >=60 else 'yellow' for p in list(extacted_data)]`

Comment: One comment: you do not really need the test for `80 > p` in the second `if` clause (or in the `elif` clause of the original question), since by the time this condition is evaluated, it is know the `p` has to be less then 80, by merit of failing the first `if`.

Answer (score 0):

## Readability and reusability ?

Chances are your business logic will need to be used in more than one place. Why not create a function that determines the color, then use list comprehension to create your list?

```
def colors(x):
    retval = 'yellow'
    if (x >= 80):
        retval = 'orange'
    elif(80 > x >= 60):
        retval = 'red'
    return retval


print([colors(x) for x in extracted_data])
```

## Output

```
['orange', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow']
```